# The proper way to inherit a CustomViewController with "dependencies"

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Recently I wrote an app with one single scene and `ViewController`. I had to set a custom background picture for the `View`, which the `ViewController` manages (i.e. my top view contained the `UIImageView`). Later on I had to implement some logic in `ViewController`, so that it properly rotates/changes the picture when the screen is rotated. Also I had to overwrite some properties like `preferredStatusBarStyle` for the `ViewController`.

Now I have to implement a couple more scenes / screens in my app and it turns out that they all must have the same design as this currently present screen, so I think it makes sense if I create a `CommonViewController` which contains this common rotation-related logic for background picture, so that I can inherit all my other `ViewController`s from this `CommonViewController`. The only problem I have is that `CommonViewController` "requires" that the view it manages has a `backgroundPicture: UIView` property, which I don't know how to ensure.

If I create a new file `CommonViewController` together with XIB-file, I can add the `backgroundPicture` image view in XIB and connect it with code (via regular "control-drag" approach), but apparently this won't work, as there is no guarantee that the views which inherit `CommonViewController` will have this property. What is the correct way to solve this issue without hacks on iOS in Swift?

Unfortunately I could not find a solution, maybe I've been searching for something wrong. It seems that I somehow need to inherit a `CommonViewController` for each scene (for each `CustomViewController`), but also I have to somehow set the top view of each of these controller's to be equal to some `CommonView`, so that `CommonViewController` does not crash when I try to access `@IBOutlet weak var backgroundPicutre: UIImageView!`.

---

The obvious way would be to define some method or property in the `CommonViewController`, so that the controllers which inherit it, can implement / override it, but it seems a bit hacky as it still requires copy-pasting in each `ViewController` which inherits `CommonViewController`.

How I imagined the solution: I create `CustomViewController: CommonViewController`, then I create a view controller in my Storyboard and change the "Class" property to "CustomViewController" (in property editor), then I select the view which corresponds to this newly added controller and change the "Class" property to "BackgroundImageView`. But I'm not sure if it's the correct way to do (also I doubt that`CustomViewController`will properly "connect" its`IBOutlet`field`bakcgroundImageView`with the corresponding`UIView`from`BackgroundImageView`, that's why I wanted to ask experts what they think about it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should define your base controller (`CommonViewController`) entirely in code, i.e. don't use no xibs / storyboards for the base controller. It doesn't mean you should rid off storyboards / xibs completely. Interface for alll other view controllers except `CommonViewController` may still be implemented with xibs / storyboards.

In this case `CommonViewController` implementation may look like this:

```
import UIKit

class CommonViewController: UIViewController {
    // use this property every time you need to 
    // manipulate backgroundPicture
    var backgroundPicture: UIImageView  = {
        // Replace with your image name
        let image = UIImage(named: "BackgroundPicture")!
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = image
        return imageView
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // If subclass overrides viewDidLoad() 
        // it should contain super.viewDidLoad()
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(backgroundPicture)

        // Align backgroundPicture to bounds of superview
        // You can remove this code and implement
        // your own alignment with frames or Autolayout
        backgroundPicture.frame = view.bounds

        // Send backgroundPicture to back of the view
        // Otherwise backgroundPicture may overlap views added in subclasses
        view.sendSubviewToBack(backgroundPicture)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        // If subclass overrides viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        // It should contain super.viewDidLayoutSubviews() 
        super.viewDidLayoutSubvews()

        // Align backgroundPicture to bounds of superview
        // You can remove this code and implement
        // your own alignment with frames or Autolayout
        backgroundPicture.frame = view.bounds
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea; But in your approach... is it safe to do `self.view = commonView`? In this case I won't be able to use `CommonViewController` to manage any other view, right? (because it's overwrite the view in `loadView()` and will work with some internal view, instead of the "real" view  it's meant to manage?

Comment: I have read more carefully and you are right. It's bad idea to override loadView if controller or it's subclasses use nib files. I updated my answer so it doesn't use loadView anymore